# Trying to run cilkscreen/cilkview on gcc with cilkplus

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cilk, cilk-plus

I am currently trying to use cilkscreen to find a race condition in cilk; however, I have the following problem.

```
cilkscreen ./executable
-bash: /home/ubuntu/cilkutil/bin/cilkscreen: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I have downloaded and set the PATH to reference the directory downloaded https://www.cilkplus.org/download. I am running ubuntu 13.10 on 64-bit. Cilkplus itself is working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `which cilkscreen` can find the file,
it is not that the executable cannot be found, as you would expect from the error message.

You need to install ia32-libs or a similar package provided by your distribution. The Cilk Tools are 32 bit, and trying to run them on a 64 bit system without the required libraries gives this (rather useless and misleading) error message.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, bash is unable to find the cilkscreen executable.  I assume you've downloaded https://www.cilkplus.org/sites/default/files/cilk_tools/cilktools-linux-003566.tgz and untarred it with the command

```
tar -xf cilktools-linux-003566.tgz
```

This will create the directory cilktools-linux-003566 containing the Cilk tools, as well as the necessary PIN files and the documentation.  I assume that you've added cilktools-linux-003566/bin to your PATH, right?

Does the "which" command find the executable?  If not, then your PATH variable is not set right.

- Barry Tannenbaum,
   Intel Cilk Plus Development